# Write a wildcard that matches specific delimiter in Word

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word

I'm writing a wildcard string in Word that should match:

```
{0>yadayada<}100{>yadayada<0}
```

Where yadayada can be anything EXCEPT the start of a new delimiter denoted by: {0>

This is what I have so far:

```
(\{0\>)*(\<\}100\{\>)*(\<0\})
```

This works except that the first '*' keeps matching tekst until it finds <}100{>yadayada<0}
I need to change it so that the * selects everything EXCEPT strings that contain '{0>'

I tried this by changing the first * with

```
[!(\{0>)]*
```

Or everything together:

```
(\{0\>)[!(\{0>)]*(\<\}100\{\>)*(\<0\})
```

But this evidently doesn't work.
Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
\{0>.+?(?=\{0>)
```

You only need to escape the `\{`

What this regular expression says is:

Match all strings containging `{0>` then any text one or more times `.+` and the `?` at the end tells the regex engine to do a lazy search, since `.+` will consume all characters if you let it.  The lazy search says find the least amount of characters until the next part of the regex can take over.

Then the `(?=\{0>)` says to match the next deliminter but do not include it in selection.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please note this only works if there is more than one delimiter and it will not work for the last value unless there is a delimiter at the end like so:

`{0>yadayada<}100{>yadayada<0}{0>yadayada<}100{>yadayada<0}{0>yadayada<}100{>yadayada<0}{0>`

Comment: Thanks a lot! That got me on the right track. I'm still having one last issue though.

Comment: If you want you can take a look at it.
Go to this site: http://regexpal.com/
Enter this as the regex code: \{0>[\w\W]+?(<\})(100\{>)[\w\W]+?(<0\})
and this as the text:

{0>blab
labla<}100{>bla
blabla<0} 
dafadsfdasf
{0>blablabla<}100{>blablabla<0}
dsafsdf
{0>blablabla<}0{>blablabla<0} 
fdsafdf
{0>blablabla<}100{>blablabla<0}


The problem lies in the last match. When there is anything other than 100 in <}100{> it will just keep looking for it until it gets it. I added [\w\W] so that the match can be multiline

Comment: Use this for the regex instead:  `\{0>[\w\W]+?(<\})(\d+\{>)[\w\W]+?(<0\})`

Comment: Instead of looking for `100` it now looks for one or more digits.

Comment: The problem is that I only want to match it if it is 100

Comment: Also `[\w\W]` does not mean multiline. It means word character or NOT word character.  A word character is `[0-9A-Za-z_]`  and a NOT word character is anything that is not `[0-9A-Za-z_]`. To enable multiline selections, check the box for multiline in regexpal.

Comment: Got it. Any idea how to specify matches with only the 100?

Comment: Yes. Here:  `{0>[\w ]+?(<\})(1\d+\{>)[\w ]+?(<0\})`

Comment: It will match 1, 10, 100, 1000, 11123423423, etc.  If you only want to match at 100, then simply change `1\d+` to `100`.

Comment: Actually nevermind, I've just thought of a work around. Thanks a ton for your help :)

Comment: No problem, I just learned regex and wanted to see if I could put my knowledge to the test!  Does my solution work for you?

Comment: Well this is the solution that I'm going to be using:

\{0>[\w\W]+?(<\})(\d+\{>)[\w\W]+?(<0\})

Comment: It seems that expression selects the values with the 0 as well as the 100's.  Is that what you want?

Comment: This `{0>[\w ]+?(<\})(1\d+\{>)[\w ]+?(<0\})` matches only the 100's.